# How do I get delimiter to work?

Tags: java, delimiter

I'm supposed to do format check. The program is to ask date like: `5/31/1987`. It will store 3 numbers into three different `int`. However, I couldn't get the delimiter to work. I don't want to use `scanner.useDelimiter("[/\n]")` because it requires the input to end with the delimiter as well.

```
import java.util.Scanner; // program uses class Scanner

public class DelimiterPlay {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a date to be checked using the format mm/dd/yyyy.");
        reader.useDelimiter("/");

        int mm = reader.nextInt();
        int dd = reader.nextInt();
        int yy = reader.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Your date is " + mm + ":" + dd + ":" + yy);

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't worry. No matter what you use for the delimiter, the scanner will always require the input to end with the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach this is, get the whole input as String first, then split the input with delimiter, like following:

```
import java.util.Scanner; // program uses class Scanner

public class DelimiterPlay {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a date to be checked using the format mm/dd/yyyy.");
        String[] test = reader.nextLine().split("/");

        int mm = Integer.parseInt(test[0]);
        int dd = Integer.parseInt(test[1]);
        int yy = Integer.parseInt(test[2]);

        System.out.println("Your date is " + mm + ":" + dd + ":" + yy);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `reader.useDelimiter("[/\\p{javaWhitespace}]+")`. It's using both `/` and whitespace chars as delimiter.

Your code is not working because it's only using `/` as delimiter. Which means you get whitespace characters (spaces, tabs and newlines) in the tokens. So it only accepts inputs that look like this `10/24/2017/...`. And if the input is `10/24/2017\n`, the third token is going to be `2017\n`, which will trigger a mismatch exception when the scanner tries to parse it as a int.

Alternatively, you can try pattern search in the current line.

```
import java.util.Scanner; // program uses class Scanner
import java.util.regex.MatchResult;

public class DelimiterPlay {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            do {
                System.out.println("Please enter a date to be checked using the format mm/dd/yyyy.");
                if (reader.findInLine("(\\d+)/(\\d+)/(\\d+)") != null) {
                    MatchResult result = reader.match();
                    int dd = Integer.parseInt(result.group(1));
                    int mm = Integer.parseInt(result.group(2));
                    int yy = Integer.parseInt(result.group(3));
                    System.out.println("Your date is " + mm + ":" + dd + ":" + yy);
                    break;
                } else {
                    reader.nextLine();
                }
            } while (true);
        }
    }
}
```